# How can I get the latest version number of a tagged branch in CVS?

Tags: linux, bash, cvs

If I have a repository:

```
 1.10
 |
 |
 1.11 ---- Tag: My_branch (1.11.2)
 |                |
 |              1.11.2.1
 1.12             |
 |                |
 |              1.11.2.2 **Required build**
 |
```

(Note: 1.11 has the tag My_branch_bp as the originating tag)

How can I use a CVS command at the command line to get this version number using CVS and the My_branch tag?

I have an overnight job I'd like to run to extract a build and put it into a directory named for the build (Eg. Project_1_11_4)

I can reformat the text all fine and extract the build if I know the number - what I can't work out is how to get CVS to tell me what that "Required build" number is.

Use of Bash is fine, but UIs and third party apps are fairly useless to me as I need the version number to run a bash script to create the directory and do other processing.